# Is a question with 'no' as a possible answer a bad question?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I am curious about a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125788/is-there-a-name-for-aggregation-queries-that-record-0-values) I asked today and whether or not it was a question that should be asked. I have already searched the topic and found this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183177/question-closed-because-yes-no-answer) on MSE about Yes/No questions, but I don't feel it applies specifically to my problem.

The question I asked, in short, was:

> Is there a special name for this type of query?

Why I think this is a good question:

- The query in question is a very common one seen on SO, and if there is a name for it, the name may help in flagging duplicates and pointing users in the right direction.
- The question is not specific to a single issue I am having, and therefore can be beneficial to many other SO users.
- I have researched my question to no luck, but followed all the guidelines such as proofreading my question and providing a specific example.

Why I'm afraid this isn't okay:

- The answer may simply be just 'No.'
- That could lead to a simple one word answer, because it is too hard to explain 'why' no one came up with a name.

From the MSO/MSE questions I've read, a question that can be answered so simply is not liked by some users because it has the 'give this answer to me' attitude.

Should this question be closed? I'm taking a chance to see if there is an answer, and in the case that there was it could be a very helpful question in the future. If there's not, the question was really just a dud. Should a question with a possible anticlimactic answer like that be avoided on SO?

Comment: Hmm.  I'm on the fence on whether that's too opinion-based.

Comment: @ryanyuyu as far as 'opinion based' I don't think (IMHO) that it's opinion based at all. There's either a name or there isn't. Perhaps someone has a slang term that they use for it (which could be there opinion), but if only one person uses that term I'd hardly consider it an answer.

Comment: If one one person uses that term, the voting will likely reflect that, but there are potentially several legitimate "correct answers" for defining something.  Perhaps this kind of jargon question is _possibly_ better suited for Programmers.  Even then I'm not sure it's [on-topic there](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  It's almost in the algorithm concepts and software design categories of on-topic.

Comment: First, ignoring the fact that you asked this as a yes/no question rather than a what question, even if it _does_ have a name, the answer is just one word: "Jimmy". Your question isn't inviting any comment on the connotations of the name "Jimmy", or whether your example is a paradigm of "Jimmy" or on the border because XXX, etc. So, why even focus on the fact that the answer might be "There is no name"; ask yourself whether the question would be acceptable if there _is_ one first. If you can say "yes" to that, then I think the fact that it might have a "sorry, no" answer wouldn't disqualify it.

Answer (score 10):

The question is off topic.  It's not a *programming* problem.

Having said that, were it to be asked somewhere it was on topic, my answer in the meta question you linked would apply exactly, specifically with respect to the second bullet.  You aren't *actually* interested in a yes/no answer, you want to be asking a "what" question.  You want to know, "What is this called?" and if the answer happens to be, "It has no name.", then so be it.

I mean, if someone said, "Yes, there is a name for that.", clearly it wouldn't be what you're looking to hear.  You would want to know *what that name is*, not just *that one exists*, in just the same way that when people ask, "Is it possible to do [...]?" they almost exclusively meant, "How do I do [...]?"

Comment: I will try to edit my question to have the 'what' attitude. In my specific example, do you think this question is salvageable if I do?

Comment: @McAdam331 No, as that does nothing to make it on topic.

Comment: You said yourself, "You want to know, 'what is this called?' and if the answer happens to be, 'it has no name.', then so be it." My question could be changed to that, no?

Comment: @McAdam331 Did you read the first sentence of the answer, or the second?  Fixing the form of your question does improve it, but it does nothing to address the fact that it's entirely off topic.  If you find somewhere where the question would actually be on topic, *then* improving the form would be relevant.

Comment: I fail to see how a question regarding the nomenclature of activities performed by programmers and the apps they write is off topic. You seem to have very strange criteria for what is or isn't considered on topic.

Comment: I too fail to find anything [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that says it's off topic. To me, it's a 'practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development', and one off topic bullet says 'Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for SO unless they direct involve tools used primarily for programming'. It's a matter of terminology between DB querying and programming, but I view queries as a tool, not a general software question.

Comment: @corsiKa I'm using the criteria that the site has described in its help center.  If you're using something else then I'd say *your* criteria would be the one that's strange.

Comment: @McAdam331 The help center doesn't have a comprehensive list of all of the things that are *off* topic (just a list of common mistakes).  Rather it has a list of what *is* on topic.  Programming problems are on topic (this isn't a programming problem), nomenclature questions aren't in that list.

Comment: Well, then I will concede to [Robert Harvey's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203880/what-is-the-appropriate-preferred-method-for-questions-concerning-programming) answer on that. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1):

> Is a question with 'no' as a possible answer a bad question?

No.

Comment: [Yes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773)

Comment: [Not always](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344356/4639281) @gnat

Comment: meta doesn't qualify because [it is officially different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240440/165773) @TinyGiant