# Same Question, Different Problem

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I had a JSON decoding issue - the JSON was valid, online decoders decoded, inline decode failed - which others had encountered and asked here. The solutions provided to them resolved their problem, but it wouldn't work for me.

I eventually discovered the problem and want to put it on Stack Overflow as a possible cause, but it doesn't seem right (or useful) to add it as an alternative solution when the OP's problem was different (despite the common end result) and was resolved. This is particularly true in a case where OP made an obvious error which was solved and accepted.

Is there a policy for or against options for addressing this? Answering one (or multiple) existing question(s), asking and answering my own question, something else?

**Clarification:** The issue is that the existing *question* is abstracted and therefore covers multiple scenarios solved by various solutions, but the specifics of the actual *scenario* of the existing question make it so additional discovered solutions are not relevant to the OP and may be missed by subsequent readers since the *scenario* is solved/accepted, sometimes even by a simple typo.

Should a new more abstractly worded question be posed and the solution presented, or should the proposed solution be answered on the existing question despite not really being relevant due to the specifics of the scenario attached?

Comment: *"OP's problem was different"* Who cares what OPs problem was? (a few people I guess) ... Questions are there for everyone and if someone else finds that question due to that same issue, then they would like to see all the possible solutions and check if it helps them. Creating yet another question with the same issue just makes it harder to find.

Comment: How exactly do you have the same question, but with a different problem? It seems to me that if your problem is different, then your code and/or symptoms will be different as well.

Comment: @Tom: That was my thought, but then again the details of the question may not be abstracted and ring irrelevant to the searcher and discourage them from reading through to the fifth answer. In one case OP made an obvious error which was solved and accepted. What use would adding solutions to more nuanced cases below?

Comment: Without any context I don't know how to respond.

Comment: I'm asking a question about policy/etiquette. The question is fairly generic. In the case where various mistakes or issues result in the same unwanted result, is there a standard on how to add a possible avenue of exploration? Should it always be added to the existing question, even if it is unlikely to be read because of question scenario/accepted answer is obvious? Should a theoretically duplicate but more abstracted question be posed and answered?

Comment: Depends on what the actual problem was, I guess. Answers should answer the question posted; that's the only criteria. Self-answering questions is fine (although sometimes you'll find people that disagree, especially if they're answering while you're finishing your answer).

Comment: We have edit history, so at any time (e.g. during the reopen review I just finished) we can see how post was changed. There is never need for *Edit*/*Update*, and it is much better (especially for new visitors to your post) to integrate any changes into a single coherent whole, than to tack something on the back of your post (the latter is of course quicker to do). Therefore vote to reopen, but no up vote.

Comment: @Anthon I tagged my edit as an edit because it was in response to a comment, not in response to the hold. I thought it common practice to note edits instead of retroactively making discussion nonsensical (i.e. no stealth-edit)

Comment: @GetzelR Your mistake (and you are not alone in that), is that this is not a forum but it is a Q&A site, with little or no discussion. The Q&A should make sense without having to wade through the comments. If not this site would just be as inefficient as a forum where you often have to read the whole thread. A question (or answer) should stand on its own, now imagine all the comments deleted, **that** would make your "tagging" nonsensical.

Comment: @Anthon You misunderstood. Precisely for the reasons you state, I improved the question based on the insight gained in the comments, without deleting the comments. I added the tag (which doesn't hurt the readability of the question) so if someone is reading the comments they would make sense.

Comment: @GetzelR I'm not surprised that people are misunderstanding this, I don't understand what this is about either. I am especially confused by the fact that one potential path you are willing to take is to post an even more abstract question - don't you mean you want to post a more specific question?

Comment: @Gimby I guess this is a side-effect of using a Q/A system as a reference. You wouldn't expect to find alternative solutions on a properly phrased and resolved specific question. An truly abstracted  question is a good place to list alternative solutions. A specific question phrased as an abstract question is the cause of the confusion. The solution applies to the headline/question, but not the scenario as presented and solved.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to provide an answer: as long as answer actually answers the question as posted it is perfectly fine to add one even if there is already accepted answer.

If you're asking the question:

- If you have the same question but looking for more/different answers - post bounty on existing question.
- If your question actually different but can be expressed with the same words as the other one - ask new question, link to existing one and explain how it is different. It is very likely that while explaining the difference you'll be able to come up with better title too to distinguish the question.

It is not correct to *edit* someone else existing question to add your problem.

Comment: Your second bullet point comes closest to the scenario. The issue is that the question is abstracted and therefore covers multiple scenarios solved by various solutions, but the specifics of the actual scenario make it so the discovered solution is not relevant to specific question.

Answer (score 3):

> The issue is that the existing question is abstracted and therefore covers multiple scenarios solved by various solutions

Apart from questions dealing with very common issues, that generally means the question is a bad one to begin with.

Unless you can convince me otherwise (i.e. show the question you're talking about, as well as the answer you want to post), we don't need more questions like *"What caused me to be late to work today?"*, where someone visiting that question has to dig through a never ending list of answers like:

- In my case, the bridge was open!
- My car wouldn't start
- The train was delayed for me

And we don't need any more answers like that either (*"try this"*). Because such questions are pretty useless for someone looking for a definitive answer to their well-defined problem, and throwing mud at a problem to see what sticks is something for a forum, not for Stack Overflow.

You'll have to keep researching until you found the thing that made your problem unique, or ask a question about *that*. Chances are that you simply lack the experience to realise your problem had the same cause as someone else, they just worded it differently.

Comment: I agree, but questions are phrased to communicate the faulty behavior - in this case "json_decode returning null for valid json" - because the questioner often doesn't have more info on why this is happening. Does it make sense to change the question once it is discovered that the culprit was non-UTF-8, htmlspecialchars, etc?

Comment: Then the JSON part is entirely irrelevant, isn't it? Passing the same incorrectly escaped or encoded string to MySQL would result in yet another error, the same when using it as a filename. Should we create a question for every API that accepts a string where the underlying cause is that someone doesn't properly sanitize user input? Instead we should create a canonical Q&A that explain what happens when incorrectly handling input, and how to fix it, and then we can close all questions that stem from that issue as a duplicate of the canonical one.

Comment: You can abstract to the point of uselessness, though. A more useful implementation might be an abstract question for the circumstance - seemingly valid input to _this_ function returning _this_ seemingly unwarranted error - as a repository of the various possible causes. It seems like an off-label use of this site, although it does address the problem of using a Q/A site as a reference.

Comment: Of course we'll have to decide a useful point at which to stop the abstraction, otherwise we can close any question as a duplicate of _"How can I debug my code?"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster Unfortunately the only valid answer to that question is "[you can't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344323/should-i-delete-my-answer-if-the-answer-is-no-this-is-not-possible)". ;)