# Is a description of the problem without a solution an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

If there is a posted answer which only explains how / why the problem happens, but without really saying how to fix it, what should be the action? *(If any)*

Considering, but not limited to:

- The explanation is right;
- The explanation can't fit in a comment;
- It's the only answer so far.

It's all a grey area for me, so I'm looking for some guidance on how to analyse this type of answers and where to draw the line.

---

As pointed out, to name at least one example:

Question:

> I get this error when connecting to database: {some error here}
>   This is my code: { ... }

Answer:

> You're not passing the correct arguments to the function in line: { line with error }

<sub>(I'll try to come up with more as I think of them - suggestions are welcome)</sub>

---

I tried to find light in [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) with:

> [...] The answer can be "don't do that", but it should also include "try this instead". [...]

But since sometimes with "don't do that" you can inffer the answer, I'm having a hard time drawing the line and choosing an action.

Comment: It depends on the question and the... uh, "answer".

Comment: For the answer you've described, I'd say that it's rarely the case that you should flag such an answer as "not an answer"

Comment: As for downvoting/upvoting, I'd usually decide based on how helpful you feel it would be for the OP.

Comment: I generally don't mind such answers if they are at least providing enough information to the reader to be able to devise a proper solution. But that's somewhat subjective.

Comment: If the answer you gave as an example included what the expected arguments were (not necessarily what the OP should pass in) it would be a complete answer. Without that, it would still be *an* answer, albeit incomplete/low quality and likely better off as a comment.

Comment: If it is an answer, it should be marked as an answer. If it is an explanation why the question cannot be answered, the vote of the question and answer should be appropriate.

Comment: @VladP Re: [answers that say the task is impossible to achieve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344356/4639281)

Comment: @TinyGiant There's a big difference between a question cannot be answered, and a question whose answer is that there is no answer.  If someone posts an answer to say, "you need to include your actual code for us to tell you what's wrong with it" then that's NAA, and what Vlad was referring to.  That's different from saying, "it's provably impossible to determine if an arbitrary code sample will halt, so no solution exists to that problem", which is what you're referring to (and is of course an answer).

Comment: @Servy I guess I completely misinterpreted the comment,

Answer (score 8):

Use your voting privilege. Vote up if you think it's useful, vote down if you think it's not useful. Don't vote if you're indifferent or if you're not sure about its usefulness.

It is an answer though, so you shouldn't flag it as *not an answer*.