# Question that is extraordinarily clear has been marked as needing details or clarity

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

The following is a link to the question I think should be reopened, or closed for a more applicable reason.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/71812638/14852364

The comments I received started with a suggestion to manually do something I explicitly stated I was avoiding: use the get and set syntax.

I then suggested they read my post all the way through. Obviously they missed some pretty simply stated elements of my post. I don't think they or the other person who joined in liked that. I don't know why they are both taking it so personally. They just missed something. They shouldn't make it my problem, and I was very clear.

So now there's literally nothing I can do to make this post any clearer. I am hoping some people can get over there and vote for it to be reopened. It isn't really even that big of a deal, but it's a nice to have, and *if* C# doesn't have such a feature (and if I can't build it somehow), then maybe I can post a recommendation that the functionality be added.

But mostly I want to know that I can come on here and ask questions and not have to assume that it's just going to be downvoted and closed for literally no reason (it has happened before), or else I'm going to have to go back to asking for help in the YouTube comments sections.

Comment: A word to the wise about posting on Stackoverflow.  Your interaction style with people that engage to help will have a lot to do with whether people reading your question and comments will be prone to try to help or more likely to try to get rid of your question.  While we'd all like downvotes and closevotes to be entirely objective, in reality, they aren't - they are reader's opinions and opinions are influenced by your interaction style.   This probably could have played out differently.  You do attract more answers with honey. 
Please take that into account in the future.

Comment: Also keep in mind that what seems "extraordinarily clear" to you is often not the same to others and it is actually your job to fix the question when someone doesn't fully understand it (if you want further help from them or others), not argue with them about how clear your question is.  The very "extraordinarily clear" in your title here in meta seems to illustrate that you don't fully understand that it isn't your opinion on what is or isn't clear that matters, but rather the opinion of your readers that matters.

Comment: [Screenshot of the deleted question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74T76.png)

Comment: Your only options are Stack Overflow and Youtube (of all places) ? What about Reddit? Quora? Codidact? Discord? One thing that I really see happening often is that people try to cram ALL their questions on Stack Overflow, even though that is absolutely NOT what you should be doing. Only on-topic non-duplicate questions go on Stack Overflow. Some questions belong on Stack Overflow, some on another site in the network, a lot of questions belong on any of the other sites which are not a knowledge base. Some belong on no site at all, but in a classroom.

Comment: Where would it work on YouTube? In live streams? Usually there are way *too many* comments (incl. spam comments of various sorts—it drowns in the other comments. Very few content creators moderate the comment section) or *too few* (not enough attention). A sweet spot is needed or the content creator responds to every comment (very seldom, though there [are exceptions](https://www.youtube.com/c/AndreasSpiess/videos)). Do you have some examples of where it works?

Comment: **ALWAYS edit the question** and **NEVER post a new one.** If you post a new one you are vulnerable to downvotes for deleting a question and or for posting a duplicate question. I tried posting a new one and ended up with 4 downvotes in the process.

Answer (score 16):

The first two comments by [gunr2171](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043380/gunr2171) answer your question perfectly:

> I'm not really sure what you're after. There are only three (relevant) types of members for a type: methods, properties, and fields. Properties MUST have at least a setter or getter. If you're not looking to use the auto-properties (the `{ get; set; }` after a property), then you'll need to write your own boilerplate code.

> Then your first code block sounds like your solution.

To put it in a more straightforward way like you asked:

**What you want to do is not supported by the language <sup>(AKA, ["[your] thing is impossible"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/126903921))</sup>.**

That's just it. Now, should the question be reopened? No. Because it's not really useful to future readers. One might argue that it was closed for the wrong reason<sup>1</sup>, however, I suspect that the close votes came *after* you received a clear answer in the comments as indicated above and you still insisted that that wasn't enough. So, people were confused, and consequently voted to close as "unclear". I would have done the same.

Relevant discussion: [Where is the line for yes/no questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258630/8967612)

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>There used to have a ["too localized"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252034/8967612) close reason, which might be applicable here.</sub>

Comment: I personally don't see why the question was closed.  It is clear what the OP wants to do - particularly with the back and forth in the comments.  The answer is that the language doesn't do what the OP wants to do.  That's the answer.  People apparently just wanted to close it because they didn't like that the OP wanted a different solution than what was being proposed.  An answer that simply said, the language doesn't do what you're asking for - here are your alternatives - pick one - would have perfectly sufficed and answered what the OP was asking for.

Comment: ***"The first two comments by gunr2171 answer your question perfectly"***  So, why didn't someone just write write that as an answer then?  Why did it need to get closed?  I suspect it was voted for closure because people didn't "like" the question and perhaps didn't like the OP's interaction style.  Not because it wasn't clear what was being asked.  IMO, these are the wrong reasons to vote to close.

Comment: @jfriend00 _"An answer that simply said, the language doesn't do what you're asking for - here are your alternatives"_ And that answer was provided (albeit in the comments) but the OP wasn't satisfied _and_ failed to explain what _else_ they expect in an "answer". _That_ was the "unclear" part, IMO. Please also note that a trail of the comments under the original post was deleted; some of which carried an entitlement tone on the OP's part and were borderline rude (though admittedly, that, in itself, is not a close reason).

Comment: Yeah, an interaction style can drastically increase the odds of getting close votes too.  Not that that's right, but it is how the stackoverflow world works.  If there are more unpleasant interaction style comments that were deleted, then I'm not surprised at all that it got close votes (even if that's the wrong reason to vote to close).  Probably more appropriate to downvote than closevote in that case.

Comment: @jfriend00 _"So, why didn't someone just write that as an answer"_ I can't speak for the users who interacted with the OP in the comments but I can speculate. The reason could be that the question was too localized, or thought it might be an XY problem. The important part that I think you're missing is that when the OP received that "answer", they didn't say "ok, post it as an answer". Instead, they more or less said "I don't like that. It doesn't answer my question. If you don't know the answer, move along" and didn't elaborate on their expectations. _That's_ what (I think) made the q unclear

Comment: What do you mean by "too localized"?  And, is that a close vote justification?  As for the OP's interaction style, I left them a comment here in meta about that. This could have played out differently with a different interaction style.  Not sure that's a legit reason for closing, but the reality is that it does influence people.

Comment: @jfriend00 I didn't say it's a close vote justification (though, it used to be). I said that people _might_ have refrained from posting an answer because they found the question too localized (which is entirely their right) or for any other reason. What's important is what happened after that. I don't know exactly when the first close vote was submitted but I _suspect_ it happened after the OP's replies which made the question more confusing (because their expectations were no longer clear).

Comment: I was legitimately asking what is "too localized"?  I'm not familiar with that term in the context of SO questions.

Comment: @jfriend00 [Good discussion of Too Localized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308837/make-it-easier-to-close-job-shop-gimme-teh-codez-questions) and why it, along with many of the subsequent rewording/replacements, was pulled.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh, sorry I missed that. It simply means that the question is unlikely to help future readers. See the linked post in the footnotes of this answer for more info. The other linked post about yes/no question is also somewhat relevant here.

Comment: OK, glad that reason for closing is gone.  Besides putting the burden on someone asking for help to try to frame their question in a way that could help others (a ridiculous burden in my opinion), it would also encourage other bad habits (like trying to make their question generic with pseudo-code) which just hides what the real problem is and leads to unclear questions.  [End of digression]

Comment: @jfriend00 "too localized" close reason still exists, it is just worded more confusingly due to a misguided rework as "not reproducible or caused by a typo". The guidance is still the same, though: the issue is resolved in a way unlikely to help other readers. Let's not forget what our mission is (stated plainly in the Tour, btw) - to build a repository of knowledge, not the best help desk in the world. The burden *is* on the author to make their question useful to others, there is nothing ridiculous about it.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine "_[do not pretend to be able to predict the future; close only based on the evidence in front of you.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348025/479156)_"

Comment: @Ivar and ironically enough, the new wording lead to the most confusing close reason we have (apart from the "opinion-based" one). Old or new reasoning hasn't changed, Shog's post is about clarifying what are the *objective* parts of "not being helpful to future readers" as opposed to trying to predict the usefulness. If the issue is *inseparable* from the OPs exact code / context, it's still "no repro or typo". If there might exist a user that will get in this *exact* context, then it isn't "too localized". P.S. There is currently a motion to revise this close reason to remove ambiguity.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I'm not an SME on the matter, but to the untrained eye it looks like a simple "No, that's not possible" answer (preferably with some reasoning, just like the commends of gunr2171) would suffice ([and are perfectly on-topic AFAIK](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344323/should-i-delete-my-answer-if-the-answer-is-no-this-is-not-possible)). The fact that they already have the best way to do so is irrelevant/can be pointed out in the answer. If that helps someone else in the future with the same question, then we most certainly contribute to our mission.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - Let's not forget that the key to building such a repository of knowledge is attracting people with questions and answers and we do that by helping people, even if their question isn't perfectly written.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine -  Personally, I think that helping people get answers to their questions should be the ***"main thing***" and out of that will come plenty of a repository of knowledge.  If that bar for a newbie to post is that they have to somehow figure out how to ask a question that will be a meaningful add to the repository of knowledge otherwise their question will be rejected, that's just ridiculously too hard for a newbie to grasp.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's why we have tools to act on the post after it is posted, such as editing. All we "require" of new users (and all users) is that they post an answerable question. I don't think that is asking too much.

Comment: My personal opinion is this question shouldn't have been closed as unclear and would have benefited from receiving a "No, this isn't possible" answer. There isn't ambiguity in this case, the OP was clear in why they wanted what they wanted. Their reasoning may be weird or ridiculous, but that doesn't make it unclear.

Comment: @KevinB - An answerable question is fine, but that isn't what was being discussed in the sub conversation here about "too local" which can be a perfectly answerable question that just isn't high on the value chain for long term reference for others and thus could be eligible for closing because it's "too local".  I was sharing that I think that's a ridiculous bar for a newbie to understand.  They just need to post a clear, answerable question that is on-topic.  That should be enough.